# Android: Null Pointer Exception in Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, nullpointerexception

I have a dialog box to be shown with two edittextboxes in it.

[image]

When I fill the fields and click on the submit button, I need to save the values in database. I am trying to get the values entered in the fields, but the Null Pointer Exception is raised.

My code is follows

```
 View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Context)
                    .setTitle(R.string.Details)
                    .setView(v)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            })
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.Submit,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    final EditText txtname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                                    final EditText txtnumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                                    Save(txtname.getText().toString(),txtnumber.getText().toString());
                                }
```

when I debug and checked, It shows the txtname and txtnumber values as empty. Where did I went wrong? I was using a layout to show the fields

The layout is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="FirstName LastName"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10" />

</TableRow>
```

Please help me out to solve this exception!!

Comment: When you have an exception, always provide the stack trace and the line being referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `txtname` and `txtnumber` are null

i.e

```
final EditText txtname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 final EditText txtnumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

when you are trying to access null reference you will get `NullPointerException`

Try to get them like this

```
final EditText txtname=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 final EditText txtnumber=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at the wrong place. Try using:

```
final View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
```

and than

```
final EditText txtname=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText txtnumber=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

to find the EditText at the "v" view.

Comment: same comment. v should be final to be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided the full code and a stack trace, I'm taking a wild guess, but I'm assuming it's correct:
You're fetching the edit texts using findViewById from the activity's content view and not from the inflated view.
Change:

```
findViewById(R.id.editText1);
findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

to

```
v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Comment: except in this case v should be final to be accessible in this scope<

Comment: Yep. Your solution is easier

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the views from the dialod's layout

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
    final EditText txtname=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText txtnumber=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                                Save(txtname.getText().toString(),txtnumber.getText().toString());
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

please check the resource id it will also make cause for NPE.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` is relative to the Activity. Your views are not in the activity, but rather in the dialog. You need to call

```
dialog.findViewById
```

from this scope.